Can we not simplify the order statistic formula?
I feel like I understand the logic behind why the formula for the order statistic is
$$
F_{X_{(r)}}(x) = \sum_{j=r}^{n} \binom{n}{j} F_X(x)^j[1-F_X(x)]^{n-j}
$$
where the equation is basically saying that
$$
F_{X_{(r)}}(x) = \sum_{j=r}^{n} \mathbb{P}(\text{exactly } j \text{ elements} \leq x)
$$
which since all these outcomes are disjoint we should be able to say that
$$
F_{X_{(r)}}(x) = \mathbb{P}((\text{exactly } r \text{ elements} \leq x) or(\text{exactly } r+1 \text{ elements} \leq x)or\cdots(\text{exactly } n \text{ samples are} \leq x))
$$.
So intuitively I thought, if at least r elements are $\leq x$ then exactly r or r+1, or $\cdots$ n samples are $\leq x$ and if r or r+1, or $\cdots$ n samples are $\leq x$ then at least r elements are $\leq x$. Thus it looks like
$$
F_{X_{(r)}}(x) = \mathbb{P}(\exists r\text{ samples}\leq x)=\binom{n}{r} F_X(x)^r
$$.
This makes sense to me since if you can show that there are r samples which are less than x then you can forget about the other n-r samples and guarantee that the r-th smallest element will be less than x and vis a versa.
I cannot find my simpler equation anywhere I look and it seems to contradict the equation for F_{X_{(1)}}(x). Where did I go wrong with my logic?

Your "simplification" overcounts the cases where more than $r$ elements $\le x$.  Thus if $n = 2$ and $r=1$, an outcome where both samples $\le x$ will contribute to both $\mathbb P(X_1 \le x)$  and
$\mathbb P(X_2 \le x)$. The result is that it is quite possible for your formula to give a result $> 1$, which is clearly wrong because it's supposed to be a probability.

That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a ton!
